# Hibernate Annotations together with EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, exception

I've created a Jar module with a hibernate dependency of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and the Jar module compiles properly. That Jar module is referenced by a War module which has a hibernate dependency of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

At run-time the War module gives an exception of

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
```

and followed by

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/Table;)V
```

It seems there is an incompatibility of the versions of hibernate. Once the dependency is removed from the Jar module. All work fine. But I need that dependency for that Jar module. How can I overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Hibernate 3.6 `hibernate-annotations` were merged into `hibernate-core` (which is a transitive dependency of `hibernate-entitymanager`). You don't need to declare `hibernate-annotations` explicitly anymore.

Comment: But as he said, he needs the hibernate dependency in the jar.

Comment: I have hibernate annotations in my Jar module. I need to resolve it through a dependency. Otherwise, it gives compilation errors. Whats the dependency should be used to resolve hibernate annotations for that stand-alone Jar module. Is there specific versions for those ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make sure the hibernate versions in the jar and the war are the same?

Comment: I tried that way as well by adding 3.5.6-Final to both the dependencies. The same exception though.

Comment: What does the maven dependency tree show?
`mvn dependency:tree` I think. Maybe there is some other artifact with a dependency on another hibernate version?